# Python tkinter mouse event & label border

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, mouseevent

I have a gui code is about some lebel in canvas, and when I move the mouse over a lebal, it's background turns red, and when I move away, it goes back to its original color.
But I havec one more special requirement. I hope that when moving out of the label, the color changes back when it is 3 pixes away from the label border,not immediately upon leaving the label

```
import tkinter as tk

def create_labels_on_canvas(canvas):
    def label_enter(event):
        event.widget.config(bg='red')

    def label_leave(event):
        x, y = event.x, event.y
        label_width = event.widget.winfo_width()
        label_height = event.widget.winfo_height()
        if x < 3 or y < 3 or x > label_width - 3 or y > label_height - 3:
            event.widget.config(bg='white')

   
    for i in range(3):
        for j in range(3):
            label_text = str(i*3 + j + 1)
            label = tk.Label(canvas, text=label_text, font=('Helvetica', 16), bg='white')
            label.grid(row=i, column=j, padx=10, pady=10)
            label.bind("<Enter>", label_enter)
            label.bind("<Leave>", label_leave)


root = tk.Tk()
root.title("3x3 Label Text")
canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width=300, height=300, bg='white')
canvas.pack()
create_labels_on_canvas(canvas)
root.mainloop()
```

Here's my code, but this part is not working, the color still changed when I leave the label

```
if x < 3 or y < 3 or x > label_width - 3 or y > label_height - 3:
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to wait for three pixels, you need to know where the edges of the label are on the canvas and then you need to be tracking the mouse movement from the time you leave the label to the time you are 3 pixels away in the X or the y direction. Your label_leave event is a single event which should give you the x and y value always but then it is finished before your mouse moves 3 pixels.

Comment: I understand, but is there any way to exec this function correctly?

Answer (score 0):

As already been said, your function 'leave' happens once after you left the label. It will not be checking after you left your label. Also this line is confusing:  `if x < 3 or y < 3 or x > label_width - 3 or y > label_height - 3` it means an opposite (inside 3 pixels), so always true when you are leaving a label. You may play with the mouse position and functions and check somehow position all the time… But what I would do is just use a parent Frames, which will be "bigger" than labels and so when you left frame, label will change color. That is my code:

```
import tkinter as tk

def create_labels_on_canvas(canvas):
    def label_enter(event: tk.Event):
        event.widget.config(bg='red')

    def label_leave(event):
        event.widget.winfo_children()[0].config(bg='white')  # i.e. config the label of the frame

    for i in range(3):
        for j in range(3):
            label_text = str(i * 3 + j + 1)
            base_label_frame = tk.Frame(canvas, bg="white")  # this will be the main frame

            # add label as a child of frame
            label = tk.Label(base_label_frame, text=label_text, font=('Helvetica', 16), bg='white')
            label.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=3, pady=3)  # your 3 pixel separation
            base_label_frame.grid(row=i, column=j, padx=10-3, pady=10-3)  # -3 to adjust
            label.bind("<Enter>", label_enter)
            base_label_frame.bind("<Leave>", label_leave)


root = tk.Tk()
root.title("3x3 Label Text")
canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width=300, height=300, bg='white')
canvas.pack()
create_labels_on_canvas(canvas)
root.mainloop()
```

As far as I understand you don't want to make that extra 3 pixels, when you enter the label, so that part of the code is unchanged. So I just put labels inside the frames whith pad x, y of 3. So your labels inside will expand cells by 3 pixels in all side, so your frame will be "increased" by 3. Than just bind frame on leave instead, so when you leave it, you will change color back(will happens in a distance of 3 pixels from label). Also, just to make final result same as yours (no really need to do this) I decrease pads of frames by 3, to make a "balance"

Comment: Thanks for your kindly reply, but I just want to try if there is any way to doing function whebn mouse is 3 pixes away from the label border.

Comment: And this is a simplified example; the actual code is more complex than just changing colors. So, the method you provided doesn’t work for me, but thank you anyway.